# AucTeX turn off line breaks

Tags: line-breaking, auctex

In AucTeX I do not want line breaks to appear when I open the .tex with a different editor e.g. on [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/). I want lines to appear as if they are broken, so I can see everything in the default 80 column width. To do this I use `M-q`. I.e. the only time I want there to actually be a break is when I finish a paragraph, and hit `return`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you want: does "Options > Line Wrapping in This Buffer > Word Wrap (Visual Line mode)" help?

Comment: Thanks, using your information I found more information on [visual-line-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visual-Line-Mode.html)